# Decimal Value Set as 0 in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to get a random decimal from 0.75 to 1.25

```
let incomeCalc = Decimal((arc4random_uniform(50)+75)/100) 
print("incomeCalc") 
print(incomeCalc)
```

Why does this print 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arc4random_uniform` return an integer type so you are doing integer math. You need to be doing floating point math.

```
let incomeCalc = Decimal(Double((arc4random_uniform(50)+75))/100)
```

By casting the value before you do the division, you get a Double result which is passed to your `Decimal` initializer.

Or you can do:

```
let incomeCalc = Decimal((arc4random_uniform(50)+75))/100
```

which creates the `Decimal` before the division is done.

Comment: I have tested this line "        let incomeCalc = Decimal((arc4random_uniform(50)+75)) / 100
" and it worked, is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: Yes, that's another good solution. Get the `Decimal` in the range 75 - 125 and then divide that result by 100.

Comment: Thank you, I'll mark this as correct as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the code below which gets a random number between 75 - 125 and then divides it by 100

```
let incomeCalc = Decimal((arc4random_uniform(50)+75)) / 100
print("incomeCalc") 
print(incomeCalc)
```